# Why does my Side menu snaps back when i lift my finger, when swiping in my CN1 app?

Tags: codenameone

In my Codenameone app i have built a side menu, but i have 2 cosmetic issues with it.

1. When i swipe from the left and i lift my finger in the screen space, slightly further than the menu finishes, the menu snaps back. It doesn't snap back if i lift my finger in the space the menu will expand to. Is there a way to make the side menu stay on the screen when i swipe?
2. My main page has a vertically scrollable container. When i open the side menu, it doesn't disable my main page so i am still able to scroll my main page container by moving my finger on the space to the right of the menu. Are we able to disable the main page content by default when the menu is open?

For ref, my menu is along the design of [this tutorial](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tutorial-create-a-gorgeous-sidemenu.html), with a very simple example being:

```
public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
    hi.add(new Label("Hi World"));

    Toolbar t = new Toolbar();
    hi.setToolbar(t);
    t.setTitle("Title");
    Label logoLabel = new Label("");
    logoLabel.setTextPosition(Label.BOTTOM);
    logoLabel.setText("label text here");
    t.addComponentToSideMenu(logoLabel);

    hi.show();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of closing back seems to be hardcoded to a quarter of the screen here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/Toolbar.java#L1380

There might be other points in the code that implement this logic. It might be possible to change that to make that logic configurable via theme constants. But right now this is hard coded.

Comment: OK, so i read that there is nothing currently i can do to workaround. Looking at the Facebook and BBC News apps i see no swipe gesture on their menu -TBH their menus look like pages rather than a side menu - so i think i will go with disabling swipe and accessing the menu through a toolbar top left hamburger button. Cheers